# DotNetNuke Text/HTML module 'style'

Tags: dotnetnuke

How can I control what 'styles' show up in the 'style' drop down box of the Text/HTML module in DotNetNuke?

Is there also a way to edit the 'styles' that are currently in the drop down box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to manually edit the fckstyles.xml configuration file.  Patrick Renner explains the process in his blog post [Optimizing the FCKEditor for DNN](http://www.patrickrenner.com/Home/articleType/ArticleView/articleId/53/Optimizing-the-FCKEditor-for-DNN.aspx).